# Dictation workflows don't activate keypress

Tags: applescript, voice-dictation

I'm unable to get Dictation to run the keypress portion of a workflow. I've tried recording a keystroke in Automator, and manually writing an AppleScript (with both key code and keystroke commands); they always work when I run them from Automator, but not from Dictation.

I know the scripts are running because if I put another command into the script, it will perform it when I speak the Dictation keyword.

Edit: After more experimenting I've found that AppleScripts in the DictationServices Workflow's folder will execute commands that don't work in scripts saved to other locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got an error message which answered my question: com.automator.runner.xpc is not allowed to send keystrokes.

Comment: Maybe you could grant it access to Accessibilty